# Providing access to private packages for npm install from Git repo during Docker build

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm

I have a team of developers working on a web-application which contains multiple Node.js services. We extracted some functionality into packages (hosted in our private Git host) that are used by 2 or more of these services.

We want to use Docker to ease the setup pain for developers. The best solution I came up with is having the devs store their GITLAB_USERNAME and GITLAB_PASSWORD or a ACCESS_TOKEN inside an `.env` file and use that during the build to install the packages before triggering the regular `npm install`.

```
RUN npm install -S git+https://${GITLAB_USER}:${GITLAB_PASSWORD}@git.my.company/project/packages/package1.git
```

That will still require the devs to insert their password/username or access token. **Are there better ways to achieve this AND pick up changes from the single `packages` I install this way?**

`npm link` ing and mounting the folders inside the container is possible but this could end up pretty confusing.

I know about [Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) but not to which extend it will help me solve my problem.